# Converting JArray to DataTable

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to serialize a DataTable in a list of other items to JSON and then deserialize it back into a DataTable but I'm continually getting an error. I've quoted the error below. In my code below you can see how I've attempted to convert it based on other answers I found.

````
```
public static class Globals
    {
        public static string FILE_NAME = null; 
        public static string FILE_PATH = null;
        public static string CAD_FILE_NAME = null;
        public static List<String[]> POINTS = null;
        public static DataTable DT = null;
        public static Canvas CAD_CANVAS = null;
        //public static Data

        public static void SaveGlobals()
        {
            List<Object> saveList = new List<Object> { FILE_NAME, FILE_PATH, CAD_FILE_NAME, DT, CAD_CANVAS };

            JsonSerialization.WriteToJsonFile<List<object>>(FILE_PATH, saveList);
        }

        public static void LoadGlobals()
        {
            List<Object> saveList = JsonSerialization.ReadFromJsonFile<List<object>>(FILE_PATH);

            FILE_NAME = (string)saveList[0];
            FILE_PATH = (string)saveList[1];
            CAD_FILE_NAME = (string)saveList[2];
            DataTable DT = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(saveList[3], typeof(DataTable));
            CAD_CANVAS = (Canvas)saveList[4];
        }
    }

```
```

public static class JsonSerialization
    {
        public static void WriteToJsonFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false) where T : new()
        {
            TextWriter writer = null;
            try
            {
                var contentsToWriteToFile = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToWrite);
                writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, append);
                writer.Write(contentsToWriteToFile);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (writer != null)
                    writer.Close();
            }
        }

        public static T ReadFromJsonFile<T>(string filePath) where T : new()
        {
            TextReader reader = null;
            try
            {
                reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
                var fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(fileContents);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.Close();
            }
        }

```
````

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'    SurveyAmateurApp    C:\Users\Tim\source\repos\Survey Amateur\WpfApp1\Globals.cs 37  Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings'   SurveyAmateurApp    C:\Users\Tim\source\repos\Survey Amateur\WpfApp1\Globals.cs 37  Active

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Apologies, edited them in.

Comment: Try to create a class with the variables and serialize that instead of List<object>

Answer (score -1):

I created a class with those variables and serialized that instead of a list of the variables. See below for the class I created.

```
public class JobFileClass
{
    public string FILE_NAME { get; set; }
    public string FILE_PATH { get; set; }
    public string CAD_FILE_NAME { get; set; }   
    public DataTable DT { get; set; }
    public Canvas CAD_CANVAS { get; set; }

    public void SaveJob()
    {
        List<Object> saveList = new List<Object> { FILE_NAME, FILE_PATH };

        JsonSerialization.WriteToJsonFile<List<object>>(FILE_PATH, saveList);
    }

    public void LoadJob(string filepath)
    {
        List<Object> saveList = JsonSerialization.ReadFromJsonFile<List<object>>(filepath);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).